# About congruence of two triangles

Tags: geometry

In Euclidean geometry, we know that SSS, SAS, AAS (or equivalently ASA) and RHS are the only 4 tools for proving the congruence of two triangles. I am wondering if the following can be added to that list:-

If ⊿ABC~⊿PQR and the area of ⊿ABC = that of ⊿PQR, then the two triangles are congruent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If two triangles (in fact, any two polygons) are similar, with scale factor $k$, then the ratio of their areas is $k^2$.  If the areas are equal then $k^2=1$ which implies that $k=1$, and therefore the triangles are congruent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the statement holds true; equality of the three angles and the area of the two triangles implies congruence. The area of a triangle is dependent of the three sides, so one can use [Heron's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula) to proof this statement.